# PHP PDO escaping double quote on update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my local environnement everything is working fine but when I move my site on GoDaddy and I try to update a post, an '\' is added in front of each double quotes.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE '.$_REQUEST['id'].' SET description_'.$_REQUEST['lang'].' = :desc where id = 1';

    try
    {
        $prepare = $bd->BD_Interne->prepare($sql);
        $result = $prepare->execute(array(":desc" => $_REQUEST['raw_desc']));
        $_SESSION['update'] = "good";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $_SESSION['update'] = "bad";
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Is it a mysql configuration issue or I have to do something in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's work of directive **magic_quotes_gpc**
see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

> function **addslashes** returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).
>
> The PHP directive magic_quotes_gpc was on by default before PHP 5.4,
> and it essentially ran addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data.

You can read how disable magic quotes on GoDaddy here: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/disable-magic-quotes-8383